# Reducing the Tx power of ble for android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a ble application for android trying to reduce the transmission power. With the [BluetoothGatt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt) class it doesn't seem to be capable of changing the transmission power of ble. I want to keep the app from transmitting ble packets at a higher range, keeping it only within a few feet for security purposes. The peripheral already has a low RSSI so that is fine.

It looks like [AdvertiseSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings) can change the advertising power but I don't think this will help me when it comes to transmitting packets.

Is changing the ble Tx even possible?

Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case i added Min and Max RSSI if the Beacon RSSI in that range i show it on the app otherwise its not shown.

I think you cannot change the TX power unless you have access to the Beacon Configuration.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying what you mean by "unless you have access"